# dynamically added vue component is not rendering

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

i have an html section(which is coming from a serve) with vue components inside in it then when i insert it on page (when a button is clicked) the components inside it are not showing(rendering).

here is my html which is inserted when a button is clicked.

```
<section class="flex items-center md:w-11/12 xl:w-9/12 mx-auto">
    <div class="px-10 w-1/2 flex flex-col">
        <h1 class="text-gray-400 mb-3 font-bold capitalize">
            <customize-text :content="{inner_text: 'We Design Web'}"></customize-text>
        </h1>
        <h1 class="text-2xl">
            <customize-text :content="{inner_text: 'Even the all-powerful Pointing has....'}"></customize-text>
        </h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to compile that component **at runtime**, not at build-time. For that you need the `vue-runtime-compiler`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to compile that component **at runtime**, not at build-time. For that you need the `vue-runtime-compiler`.

Vue usually is compiled at build-time. That means that the following template

```
<template>
  <div>Hello World!</div>
</template>
```

would be compiled by `npm run build` into the following script **at build-time**

```js
new Vue({
  render (h) {
    return h('div', 'Hello World!')
  }
})
```

If you want the client/browser to be able to compile it, you have to use the `vue-runtime-compiler`.

Have a look at the Vue docs. Specifically here: https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only